# nodejs imapd reader not working on remote server (ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: node.js, imap

I have e simple code that gets email from another server.
Locally in my machine works fine but when I install it in a remote server (AWS) get this error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 200.80.43.104:143
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1138:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '200.80.43.104',
  port: 143,
  source: 'socket'
}
```

My code is:

```
const imapConfig = {
  user: Email,
  password: Password,
  host: Server,
  port: 143,
  tls: false,
};
      const imap = new Imap(imapConfig);
      imap.once('ready', () => {
        imap.openBox('INBOX', false, () => {
          imap.search(['FLAGGED'], (err, results) => {
            const f = imap.fetch(results, {bodies: ''});
            f.on('message', msg => {
              msg.on('body', stream => {
                simpleParser(stream, async (err, parsed) => {
      });
  
      imap.once('error', err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  
      imap.once('end', () => {
        console.log('Connection ended');
      });
  
      imap.connect();
    } catch (ex) {
      console.log('an error occurred');
    }
  };
```

Thanks in advance

I am trying to get emails on a nodejs server

Comment: Do you control the imap server yourself?

Comment: That IP will not allow you to connect (possibly from that location). First, nearly all servers require security to use remotely (eg with TLS or StartTLS).  Second, many hosted servers block from cloud hosting because they consider it an end user service and attacks come continuously from cloud server farms.  And users don’t get their email using AWS addresses.